# Redux: call mapStateToProps for local changes

Tags: angularjs, redux

I have a page with an exchange rates, and there is a select control on the page with different currencies.

I have an action to load rate for an exchange pair not in a state yet.
So, every time I change the select box, I'm calling an action to load new rate pair from API.

My mapStateToProps:

```
mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        rateState: selectExchangeRates(state, this.currencyFrom, this.currencyTo)
    };
}
```

My action looks like this (i'm using angularJS, but it doesn't matter):

```
exchangeRates(from, to) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = selectExchangeRates(getState(), buy, pay);
        if(state.isLoading || state.isRequested) return this.$q.resolve();
        ...
        /* here is async request for exch pair, which is dispatching request state and after - result or error */
    };
}
```

The problem is, when in a form I'm switching to existing rate, there is no action dispatched. So, the question is - how can I update my `mapStateToProps` withut state change?

I don't have a reducer for a form, because I don't need to store it state. Parameters currency from and to is local.

Is it OK practice to do something like:

```
onPairChange(from, to){
    this.props = Object.assign(this.props, this.mapStateToProps(this.$ngRedux.getState()));
}
```

Or maybe there is a better solution do exists? Thx

Answer (score 0):

`mapStateToProps` can take one more argument, often called `ownProps`. The presence of this second argument will change the behavior of `connect` such that it won't only be called on a Redux state change, it'll also be called on props change too:

https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#ownprops